# LocalForage async/await getItem() wait for 2 variables and then finish loading

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, local-storage, localforage

I'm new to the Javascript async calls and understanding promises. I'm so used to Do This, Wait for This.

I am using localforage in my site, and I need to get data from 2 sources.

```
var ordersRaw = null
var itemsRaw = null
localforage.getItem('ordersRaw').then((res) => {
    if(res) {
        ordersRaw = res
    } 
})
localforage.getItem('itemsRaw').then((res) => {
    if(res) {
        itemsRaw = res
    } 
})
if(ordersRaw && itemsRaw) {
    // now load the screen
} else { console.log('NO DATA') }
```

After I have these 2 pieces of data, finish loading the screen by running a function

```
displayWithResults()
```

But if I run it like this, it will instantly fail, because of the async functionality. and cause NO DATA to show up.

I consistently run into this issue with javascript and I can't seem to fully wrap my head around it accurately. Any help here is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to solve this:

- Nest the callbacks
- Use async await using promises
- Store the results under a single key as nested properties in an object
- Use Promise.all

It comes down to the fact that you want to retrieve **all** results asynchronously **before** performing the check.

I suggest that you use async await, it's just clean.

The code would look something like this:

```
(async() => {
    try {
        const ordersRaw = await localforage.getItem('ordersRaw');
        const itemsRaw = await localforage.getItem('itemsRaw');
        if(ordersRaw && itemsRaw) {
            // now load the screen
        } else { 
           console.log('NO DATA') }
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
})();
```

Edit: Above code executes sequentially. 
Please replace with something like:

```
const getOrders = localforage.getItem('ordersRaw');
const getItems = localforage.getItem('itemsRaw');
const [ordersRaw, itemsRaw] = await Promise.all([getorders, getItems]);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking the time! I just found something like this. It seems 'promising', hah, sorry, const finalResult = [await ordersRaw, await itemsRaw]

Comment: @Justin That is weird code. You can run await statements procedurally as if they were synchronous, that is the beauty of using async await. It looks like synchronous code, but it is actually asynchronous.

Comment: are you able to provide me with a sample as to what you are comparing too?

Comment: Sorry, there was a small syntax mistake in the self invoked function. I'm not actually typing this in an editor currently.

Comment: This code will not attempt to retrieve the two results asynchronously with each other. For that, you need to start the two `getItem()` before you `await`.

Comment: @niry You're right. Promise.all would fix this easily. I will update.

Comment: @niry I agree. Practically you probably won't notice the difference, but as this is SO I have updated accordingly.

Comment: Much appreciated @Trace & niry

Comment: @Trace I deleted my second comment because it was buggy (can't change const) and you got the point